# Checking whether a private company is a subsidiary of a public company

Tags: corporation

I am currently managing a lawsuit against a private company, let's call it "**X**". It's an Israeli company. I need to prove to the court that company **X** is actually a subsidiary of company **Y**, which is a public company in the United States. (It's a tech giant actually.)

Is there some kind of report for a public company that would show me that company **Y** holds shares of company **X**? Is this information that a public company must disclose, and if so what would that document be called? (I already looked at a bunch of important-looking reports of company **Y** and couldn't find a mention of company **X**, but I may have been looking at the wrong ones.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A public company in the US must disclose subsidiaries.  From an SEC FAQ:

> 7. Where can I find a list of a company’s subsidiaries?
>
> A list of subsidiaries must be disclosed to the SEC as Exhibit 21 to registration statements filed on Forms S-1, S-4, S-11, F-1, F-4, 10, and the annual report filed on Form 10-K.

http://www.sec.gov/investor/pubs/edgarguide.htm

You can get these filings from the SEC through the EDGAR tool:
http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

Comment: The Annual 10-K is a good place to go, with the company structure usually described at the very beginning of the document under the Part 1, Item 1 Business section.